# Can MCEdit's create chunks command handle large biomes?

Tags: mcedit

I'm trying to use MCEdit to generate new chunks for my SMP world with large biomes, but the new chunks aren't matching up with the old ones. Does MCEdit just ignore the large biomes generator option? Is there an option that I need to set, or a filter or script to add large biome support?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is any way to generate new large biomes in a world. A Google search for [settings](https://www.google.com/search?q=MCEdit+large+biomes+setting) or [filters](https://www.google.com/search?q=MCEdit+large+biome+filter) did not turn up any results. MCEdit most likely ignores the large biome generator option.